# Why server always send http 302 for css, js?

Tags: performance, azure, asp.net-web-api

I would like see cache fro static css\js files.
I use azure.

I tried add  `<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00"/>`in the webconfig, but it doen't help me.

I still see 
[image]

Comment: HTTP 304 = not changed. Uses browser cache.

Comment: But why it so long ?

Comment: If you are refering to the encircled response times, Expand them and see where the time goes. Probably the server taking "a long time" to respond with 304.